# statusbar menu item won't show UI (dialog box) on click once dock icon is disabled

Tags: macos, dialog, applescript, statusbar

I am currently having an issue with the statusbar app I have been writing in AppleScript. The app consists in a statusbar with a few menu items consistently running while the computer is on. It allows the user to check a small variety of status and performs a couple of system tasks like changing some system setting preferences or starting some apps.

With that in mind, I decided to remove the app dock icon when it is running to only have the statusbar icon displayed so I modified the .plist: (`defaults write /Applications/name_of_myapp.app/Contents/Info.plist LSUIElement -bool yes`)

Everything still works but one thing: for some menu items, a click would trigger a dialog box to request confirmation of the action and once I have modified the plist the dialog box does not show up any longer.

```
set valueRtn to display dialog "Are you sure you want to activate APPXXX?" with icon myIcon buttons {"Don't Continue", "Continue"} default button "Continue" cancel button "Don't Continue"

set buttonRtn to button returned of valueRtn
if buttonRtn is "Continue" then tell application "APPXXX" to activate
```

Anyone has an idea as to why the line of code here above will not execute any longer? I should add that any other command would work BUT the dialog box.

Thanks in advance for any kind input!

Comment: Why don't you set LSUIElement in Xcode?

Comment: Thanks @vadian for your reply (once again!). I have not used Xcode for this small app, only AppleScript. It is so small (only a A4 page script) that I think it'd be easier scripting. However you may have something in mind as regards how to set LSUIElement differently than I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

After saving the app the first time right-click on the icon and choose "Show Package Contents". Open folder `Contents` and then open `info.plist` with a text editor. Insert these two lines

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

the position in `info.plist` doesn't matter but the two lines must be inserted right before a `<key>` line

Save `info.plist` in the Text Editor. Save the project in Script Editor.

Be aware that the customization gets lost when you save the applet with `Save as...`

Comment: Thanks @vadian. It works perfectly well. It incidentally helped me realise I had another scripting error. Ultimately the terminal method works as well but your method pointed me in the right direction and does not mess with the info.plist file. A million thanks again :) Till next time!